# How to change variable value in return of render with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, return, render

```
render() {
    let inputText=this.props.searchData
    console.log(inputText);
    let Inputreg = inputText.toLowerCase()
    console.log(Inputreg)
    console.log(this.state.Product)
    let Product= this.state.Product;
    let flag = 0;
        return(
            <div>
           { this.state.Product.map((obj,index)=> {

                let productNameLow = obj.name.toLowerCase()
                console.log(productNameLow)
                var arr = productNameLow.split(' ');
                console.log(arr)
                console.log(Inputreg)
                let n =(inArray(arr, Inputreg));
                console.log(n)
                if (n > 0) {
                    return (
                            <div className ="Product" key={index}> 
                                <div className="card">
                                    {<Link to ={{pathname: './ProductDescription' , state: { item: obj } }} className="card-img-top"><img src={obj.thumbBig[0]} alt="" /></Link>}  
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h4 className="card-title">{obj.name}</h4>
                                        <p className="card-text-right"></p>
                                        <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onClick={e=>this.handleClick(obj.name,obj.price,obj.thumbBig[0],index)}/>
                                        <input type="button" value="Add to Favourite" className="fav-button" id={index} onClick={e=>this.props.getFavourite(index)}/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>       
                    )
                    {flag = 1}// flag value is not being set to 1
                }
            })}

                {(() => {
                        if(flag == 1){
                            return (
                                <div>
                                <h2>No such product exist. Try another search</h2>
                                </div>
                            )
                        } 
                    })()} // function is self invoked , although i wanted to invoke this flag condition after my if(n>0) loop is completely iterated. 

        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to return the search products according to the if(n>0)condition and set flag value to 1 , if flag value remains 0 which i have initialized to 0 only , then i want to return only message. But the flag condition should be checked after the completion of if loop.

Comment: Why are you not mapping outside the return and keep the value somewhere and simply check it's length in the return of this method and render the message is length is zero or the array if not. There is actually quite a lot that can be improved in this code. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
    let inputText = this.props.searchData;
    let Inputreg = inputText.toLowerCase();
    let Product = this.state.Product;
    let flag = 0;
        return(
           <div>
           { this.state.Product.map((obj,index)=> {

                let productNameLow = obj.name.toLowerCase()
                console.log(productNameLow)
                var arr = productNameLow.split(' ');
                console.log(arr)
                console.log(Inputreg)
                let n =(inArray(arr, Inputreg));
                console.log(n)
                if (n > 0) {
                    return (
                            <div className ="Product" key={index}> 
                                <div className="card">
                                    {<Link to ={{pathname: './ProductDescription' , state: { item: obj } }} className="card-img-top"><img src={obj.thumbBig[0]} alt="" /></Link>}  
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h4 className="card-title">{obj.name}</h4>
                                        <p className="card-text-right"></p> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>       
                    )
                    {flag = 1}
                }
            })}

             {(flag == 0) &&
                     <h2>No such product exist. Try another search</h2>

             } 
             {(flag !== 0) &&
              <h2>Some other message</h2>
             }                       
        </div>
    )
}
```

Let me know if it helped. As far as my understanding this should solve your problem

Comment: It is not setting the flag value to 1 in if(n>0) loop .

Comment: Can you just post  a minimal working code. That would be helpful